# Display splash-screen in PyQt5 during function execution

Tags: python, pyqt5, splash-screen, sleep

I have a program where I display the GUI with `PyQt5`. From my `MainWindow` I open a `QWidget` from which a function is started. While this function is running a `SplashScreen` should appear. As soon as the function is finished, the `SplashScreen` should close again. I have tried to start the `SplashScreen` from within the function. However, the `SplashScreen` does not appear.

I have used the following code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QDialog, QProgressBar, QLabel, QFrame, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import time

class Function:
    def loading(self):
        self.screen = SplashScreen()
        self.screen.show()
        time.sleep(10)
        self.screen.close()

class SplashScreen(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Spash Screen Example')
        self.setFixedSize(1100, 500)
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.frame = QFrame()
        layout.addWidget(self.frame)

        self.labelTitle = QLabel(self.frame)
        self.labelTitle.setObjectName('LabelTitle')

        # center labels
        self.labelTitle.resize(self.width() - 10, 150)
        self.labelTitle.move(0, 40)  # x, y
        self.labelTitle.setText('Splash Screen')
        self.labelTitle.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.labelDescription = QLabel(self.frame)
        self.labelDescription.resize(self.width() - 10, 50)
        self.labelDescription.move(0, self.labelTitle.height())
        self.labelDescription.setObjectName('LabelDesc')
        self.labelDescription.setText('<strong>Working on Task #1</strong>')
        self.labelDescription.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.progressBar = QProgressBar(self.frame)
        self.progressBar.resize(self.width() - 200 - 10, 50)
        self.progressBar.move(100, self.labelDescription.y() + 130)
        self.progressBar.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.progressBar.setFormat('%p%')
        self.progressBar.setTextVisible(True)
        self.progressBar.setRange(0, 100)
        self.progressBar.setValue(20)

        self.labelLoading = QLabel(self.frame)
        self.labelLoading.resize(self.width() - 10, 50)
        self.labelLoading.move(0, self.progressBar.y() + 70)
        self.labelLoading.setObjectName('LabelLoading')
        self.labelLoading.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.labelLoading.setText('loading...')

        self.setStyleSheet('''
                        #LabelTitle {
                            font-size: 60px;
                            color: #93deed;
                        }

                        #LabelDesc {
                            font-size: 30px;
                            color: #c2ced1;
                        }

                        #LabelLoading {
                            font-size: 30px;
                            color: #e8e8eb;
                        }

                        QFrame {
                            background-color: #2F4454;
                            color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
                        }

                        QProgressBar {
                            background-color: #DA7B93;
                            color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
                            border-style: none;
                            border-radius: 10px;
                            text-align: center;
                            font-size: 30px;
                        }

                        QProgressBar::chunk {
                            border-radius: 10px;
                            background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad x1:0, x2:1, y1:0.511364, y2:0.523, stop:0 #1C3334, stop:1 #376E6F);
                        }
                    ''')

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout_window = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout_window)
        self.button = QPushButton("Open", self)
        layout_window.addWidget(self.button)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.open)

    def open(self):
        self.function = Function()
        self.function.loading()


class MyApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.window_width, self.window_height = 1200, 800
        self.setMinimumSize(self.window_width, self.window_height)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.button = QPushButton("Open", self)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.open)

    def open(self):
        self.window = Window()
        self.window.show()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyApp()
    myapp.show()

    try:
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    except SystemExit:
        print('Closing Window...')
```

I have represented the function (in the original program some time consuming data processing takes place) with `time.sleep`. When I leave out the `close-function`, the 'SplashScreen' opens after the `time.sleep` is finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `time.sleep` will block the event-loop, so any GUI-related operations will be suspended until it finishes. You therefore need to explicitly force processing of any pending events, using [processEvents](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents):

```
class Function:
    def loading(self):
        self.screen = SplashScreen()
        self.screen.show()
        for i in range(100):
            self.screen.progressBar.setValue(i)
            QApplication.processEvents()
            time.sleep(0.1)
        self.screen.close()
```

Or move the time-consuming task to a worker thread, and then use signals to update the GUI:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QThread

class Thread(QThread):
    progressChanged = pyqtSignal(int)

    def run(self):
        for i in range(100):
            QThread.msleep(100)
            self.progressChanged.emit(i)

class Function:
    def loading(self):
        self.screen = SplashScreen()
        self.screen.show()
        self.thread = Thread()
        self.thread.progressChanged.connect(
            self.screen.progressBar.setValue)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.screen.close)
        self.thread.start()
```

The latter approach is usually recommended, but if the task can't be broken up into discrete steps, you may need to use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) instead.

Comment: Is it possible to emit a `dataframe` instead of an `int value` with `pyqtSignal`?

Comment: I got it by using `pyqtSignal(object)` and adding a second function (`def printdataframe(self, link)`) to the class `Function` and connecting the function to `self.thread.progressChanged.connect(self.printdataframe)`. The `link` variable gives me the `dataframe`

Comment: I run the `Qthread` from a `QWidget` and I get the following error: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the Main Thread!'`

Comment: @Mazze Please post a new question with a [mre]. The code in my answer does not produce any errors. Your error looks specific to macos, and is possibly caused by trying to perform GUI operations outside the main thread. However, that's just a guess as it's impossible to debug properly without seeing the actual code you are running.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I already solved the problem. I had another thread running somewhere, which I forgot about